# How to pack specific files in a Maven Project to specific directory in war?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a project and this directory

```
src/main/texts
```

In this directory I have o lot of file types, for example, *.txt, *.cvs, etc

I want to generate a war and I need only *.txt files of this directory in the specific directory of war, pof example:

```
war/files/*.txt
```

What maven plugin can I use to do this?
Pack all *.txt files of "src/main/texts" to the directory "files" of the war.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to " Adding and Filtering External Web Resources" of maven war plugin .
Check the maven documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html)

Sample plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>

              <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
              <directory>src/main/texts</directory>
              <!-- the default value is ** -->
              <includes>
                    <include>**/*.txt</include>
            </includes>
            <targetPath>war/files</targetPath>

            </resource>

          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move those files into separate directory and add the following to your configuration:

```xml
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
          <directory>TheFolderYouHavedecided<directory>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
```

Or the other way would be to define the folder you like:

```xml
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
          <directory>src/main/texts<directory>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*.txt</include>
          </includes>
          <targetPath>war/files</targetPath>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
```

I would recommend to reconsider your project structure and where to put which parts.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html